# Angular pass html attributes (i.e. style/class) from parent to child

Tags: angular, parent-child

I am trying to figure out a way to pass html attributes (like style and class) from a parent component to a child component without a custom `@Input()` value. I've seen examples where you can pass in `<lib-dropdown myStyle="style="width:100%;">`, but that means I have to program every single html attribute I want to use.
Plus I've seen ways, through some 3rd party angular libs I've used, where you call your child component and it somehow grabs the styles and the classes you added in `<lib-dropdown style="width:100%;"/>`.

So is there a way to do this where I don't have to create an `@Input()` value for every html attribute so I can just do `<lib-dropdown style="width:100%;"/>` and have it automatically apply to my component? Even if I have to program it in the `ngOnInit` of my child component, that's fine. Was just curious if there was a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try using service to pass HTML from parent to child.

Store HTML tags in property

```
htmlStr = "<h1> Hey There </h1>";
```

and try to call a method of service:

```
this.setHTMLService.setHtml(this.htmlStr);
```

then in the receiving component:

```
import { setHTMLService} from 'src/app/shared/service/setHTML.service';

export class ReceivingComponent implements OnInit {
 htmlExample = '';

constructor(private setHTMLService: setHTMLService) {}
}

ngOnInit() {
      this.htmlExample = this.setHTMLService.getHtmlExample();
}
```

in your template:

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlExample"><div>
```

Comment: Problem with that is I'd have to do this for every attribute I want. What I'd like to do is somehow extend the html dom, and just add my additional attributes :\

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass a lot of styles to one element, then you can use this

```
<div [styles]=[customStyles]>Child component</div>
```

but that not good practice, because for these cases better to use CSS.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that because I have to create an @Input for every html attribute I want to do that with.  Is there a way via directives to potentially do this?

Comment: are you mean html tag or html style attribute?

Comment: Either one.  For instance, If I want to add a place holder, I don't want to have to update my child component to handle it.  I want to be able to just go <lib-child-component placeholder="my child component"/>